# Can't pass data from template to controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form in which I want to pass some data and post them into an URL.
What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

`template.html`

```
<div ng-controller="statusController">
<form role="form" name="form" method="post" ng-submit="rate(ratingData)">
    <div class="form-group float-label-control">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="ratingData.title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group float-label-control">
        <label for="rating">Rating</label>
        <input id="rating" name="rating" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rating" ng-model="ratingData.rating">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group float-label-control">
        <label for="review">Review</label>
        <input id="review" name="review" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Review" required ng-model="ratingData.review">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group float-label-control text-center  ">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formmethod="post">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`controller.js`

```
angular.module('deliveryStatus', ['ngRoute'])
.component('deliveryStatus', {
    templateUrl: 'components/delivery-status/delivery-status.template.html'
})
.controller('statusController', function ($http, $scope, $routeParams, Auth, $window, $timeout, $location) {

    $scope.rate = function (ratingData) {
        $location.url('/rating');
        $http.put('/api/rating-detail', $scope.ratingData).then(function (res) {
            console.log('worked');
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error rating');
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: This will seem silly, but is the controller also named `statusController`?

Comment: @DanielD yes the controller is named `statusController` but I didn't paste it all

Comment: Could you add the whole controller code?

Comment: @DanielD I just updated my question. You have the controller there now. thanks :)

Comment: What is the error? What about your current code doesn't work. Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: In your controller you are assigning the rate function to scope not $scope.  e.g. it should be `$scope.rate = ` instead of `scope.rate = `.

Comment: @DustinHodges that was a paste error from my side. I'll update the question.

Comment: @DanielD I can't access the API. I get this error: `PUT http://localhost:4000/api/rating-detail 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Then this is not a front-end issue, but a back-end issue. Your API is saying that URL is not found. It won't matter if your client code is perfect, if your API doesn't implement that URL

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to pass the variable `ratingData` and then try to access it from the scope?

```
$http.put('/api/rating-detail', $scope.ratingData).then(function (res) {
```

Try

```
$http.put('/api/rating-detail', ratingData).then(function (res) {
```

Comment: Upon reflection, this shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `ratingData` initialised anywhere. See below code snippet, change it and it should work.

```
angular.module('deliveryStatus', ['ngRoute'])
    .component('deliveryStatus', {
        templateUrl: 'components/delivery-status/delivery-status.template.html'
    })
    .controller('statusController', function ($http, $scope, $routeParams, Auth, $window, $timeout, $location) {
        $scope.ratingData = {};
        $scope.rate = function (ratingData) {
            console.log(ratingData)

            $http.put('/api/rating-detail', $scope.ratingData).then(function (res) {
                console.log('worked');
                $location.url('/rating');
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error rating');
            });
        };
    });
```